# Utilizing nested dictionary to replace specific values in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe where I need to replace all the "yes" values with the corresponding number from a nested dictionary. The nested dictionary is composed of the row values of column 'Store' as the outer keys. The inner keys are the columns named 'A' and 'B'.

This is the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['abc', 'jan','yes','no'], ['abc', 'feb','no','yes'], ['def', 'jan', 'yes','yes'],  ['def', 'feb', 'no','yes']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Store', 'Month', 'A','B' ])

df
 
  Store Month    A    B
0   abc   jan  yes   no
1   abc   feb   no  yes
2   def   jan  yes  yes
3   def   feb   no  yes
```

This is the nested dictionary:

```
# dict = {row value in 'Store' column:{column:point value}}
dict = {'abc':{'A':5,'B':4},'def':{'A':3,'B':2}}
```

This is the desired output:

```
  Store Month    A    B
0   abc   jan    5   no
1   abc   feb   no    4
2   def   jan    3    2
3   def   feb   no    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `'yes'` by `np.nan` and `fillna` by the values of your nested dict:

```
d = {'abc':{'A':5,'B':4},'def':{'A':3,'B':2}}
out = df.replace({'yes': np.nan}).groupby('Store') \
        .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(d[x.name])).droplevel(0)
print(out)

# Output
  Store Month   A   B
0   abc   jan   5  no
1   abc   feb  no   4
2   def   jan   3   2
3   def   feb  no   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def find_num(store, col_value, col_name):
    if col_value == "yes":
        sub_dict = dict[store]
        return sub_dict[col_name]
    else:
        return "no"


for col in list(df.columns):
    if col == "Store" or col == "Month":
        continue
    df[col] = df.apply(lambda x: find_num(x['Store'], x[col], col), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using `np.where`.

(i) `map` `dict` (FYI, `dict` is the name of a dictionary constructor, I replace it with `dct` here) to "Store" to match the relevant dictionaries for each row.

(ii) flatten `df[['A','B']]` to a numpy array

(iii) iterate over result from (i) and get the values of each dictionary, and flatten the resulting list using `itertools.chain`

(iv) use `np.where` to select values based on whether the result from (ii) is "yes" or not

(v) reshape the result from (iv) into a 2D array and assign back to `df[['A','B']]`

```
from itertools import chain
mapper = df['Store'].map(dct)
flat_AB = df[['A','B']].to_numpy().flatten()
values_from_dict = list(chain.from_iterable([d.values() for d in mapper]))
df[['A','B']] = np.where(flat_AB == 'yes', values_from_dict, flat_AB).reshape(-1,2)
```

or you can directly use the DataFrame itself (but I think this is slower than the above method)

```
df[['A','B']] = np.where(df[['A','B']] == 'yes', pd.DataFrame(df['Store'].map(dct).tolist()), df[['A','B']])
```

Output:

```
  Store Month   A   B
0   abc   jan   5  no
1   abc   feb  no   4
2   def   jan   3   2
3   def   feb  no   2
```